# I am having a problem with blending my animations played by script ( animator.Play(newState); )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, blending

I am working on animating my character so it can go in all 8 directions sprinting, walking, crouching, jumping...

First I was using the animator transitions and parameters, everything worked fine, I were switching only parameters with my script, but it was getting way to messy, with to many transitions.

Then I switched to playing the animations directly from the script, using the `GetComponent<Animator>().Play(wantedState);`. However this does not blend animations and I don't know how to.

If anyone has any idea - I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

I have tried putting any other word instead of play, such as Fade, but nothing worked.

Comment: why not let the animator do it all?

Comment: Well it is to many transitions and states (almost 30 states) and all of them must be conected with one another

Comment: tbh it sounds like there'd be more code  if you do it by hand than if you do it in the animator, but you can make transitions via code.. never tried it though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`Animator.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) which hard jumps to the indicated state you are rather looking for [`Animator.CrossFade`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFade.html)

> Creates a crossfade from the current state to any other state using normalized times.